# Editing code formats, however SO states that the edit is mainly code

Tags: feature-request, edits

Sometimes, when I attempt to edit code for proper format, it (the edit window) blows up with a "mainly code" error. I'd like to assume this is an attempted workaround (which works, obviously) of the "mainly code" error. However, the "not properly formatted as code" error should catch the OP's who ask the question making code as regular text in their question. It also seems like these kinds of questions have no main point(s) (in other words, explanation[s]) as to why they are getting their error(s).

Example: [How to split pepperoni pizza into 8 equal slices using Python OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200135/how-to-split-pepperoni-pizza-into-8-equal-slices-using-python-opencv)

The "Note" part is the only real non-code text. Even then, the point of the note is unclear and doesn't clearly state the problem.

Why would such posts be allowed? Can we have (slightly) stricter editing and asking minimums so as to make sure we have enough evidence as part of the real non-code text?

**EDIT:** There are low-quality flags, I know, but this is about formatting the question.

Comment: If you're asking why the error didn't get raised when the OP originally posted the question, then the answer is precisely *because* they had not formatted their code correctly. I agree, though, that blowing up when you try to edit it is…not ideal. The question really needs to be closed, but it's hard to make heads or tails of something that is so badly formatted as to be unreadable.

Comment: Side note: you probably should not attempt editing posts of this kind as it is unlikely state after edit would be acceptable quality and hence your edit likely to be rejected as "no improvements whatsoever" or at very least time you spent editing will be lost when post automatically deleted due to quality.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm starting question edition and I'm facing more and more the unavoidable `mainly code` error. Unfortunately, I'm starting to give up as I know it will take a bunch of comment to have a proper question. Should I purely give up or flag the question as "low quality"? I don't flag yet as I consider not having the maturity for that yet.

Comment: @Al1 VLQ/NAA are tricky flags to get right. I'd recommend reading through existing posts on these flags on meta to come up with your own flagging approach/thresholds. Generally downvote is enough in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would such posts be allowed?

They're not, the system just failed to automatically reject this post (it's fallible after all).  Humans are at the time of this writing, most of the way to correcting this.

> Can we have (slightly) stricter editing and asking minimums so as to make sure we have enough evidence as part of the real non-code text?

I mean you might be able to tweak a few things, but in general you're always going to be able to trick the automated systems.  That's why there are human systems in place as well.  There's a very real chance that the *reason* the question was improperly formatted in the first place is precisely because we *don't* let people post code-only questions.  The system does *attempt* to recognize code not formatted as code, but it's not perfect and that runs the risk of having false positives if you're too strict.

Comment: The false positives is actually a good point, I guess; hence why I said "slightly".